# resize ubuntu guest drive

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 under VirtualBox 6.1.18 on a Windows 10 host.  I'm trying to increase the dynamically allocated drive from 100G to 150G.  With the guest shut down, using VB GUI I can increase the VDI size from 100G to 150G.  However, when I boot the Ubuntu guest and run `gparted` it shows the 100GB disk with no unused space.

I can open VirtualBox GUI and double check and sure enough, under Storage, the virtual drive shows

```
Type (Format): Normal (VDI)
Virtual Size: 150.00 GB
Actual Size: 47.49 GB
Details: Dynamically allocated differencing storage
```

[image: VirtualBox]

Here's what I see in `gparted`:

[image: gparted]

I also tried booting from CD and "Try Ubuntu" but gparted looks the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase VDI size of VirtualBox on Ubuntu Host - GPARTED not recognizes the new size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032869/increase-vdi-size-of-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-host-gparted-not-recognizes-the-new)

Comment: Thanks but no -- I did use the VB GUI to resize the drive, and before Start when I look at the settings it shows the larger size, so it's not a case of my using the wrong VDI file.